An error occurred while fetching the pipeline. Repository requires an endpoint Parameter name: endpoint
I am seeing the following error when trying to edit a pipeline from within Azure Devops

This happens when I click on "View Template" link in the editor

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my-devops
      type: github
      endpoint: my-ops
      name: my-ops/my-devops
      ref: main
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: build-my-test
      source: build-my-test
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

stages:
  View Template
  - template: applications/deploy.yaml@mydevops
    parameters:
      TARGET_ENV: dev

But the validation on the template itself is passing. I am suspecting that this could be related to the the 2 checkouts lines. But validation is passing. and I do need to checkout the source repo and also the repo where the template resides
template is deploy.yaml:
stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage

    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        environment: $(ADO_ENVIRONMENT_NAME)
        displayName: Deploy
        pool:
          name: self-hosted
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self # if I give this line only it works
                - checkout: mydevops # if i add this line it throws that error

                - task: Bash@3
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      # Write your commands here
                      
                      echo 'Hello world'


Are you using Azure DevOps repositories or other? Are you defining repositories resources and if so, are you setting the endpoint correctly? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition

yes i am using reposoitories corectly i double checked

A workaround would be to checkout the code and edit the pipeline in VS Code or another editor of your choice.

correct workaround is to open it in vscode and see the template, but it becomes cumbersome to checkout all the repos where these templates are locally just to view them. from Azure devops editor its just a click on Validate -> View template to see it, especially if you have a few templates

The error seems to indicate you're using a repository resource without setting the endpoint property.
From Define a repositories resource:
resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: string # Required as first property. Alias for the repository.
      endpoint: string # ID of the service endpoint connecting to this repository.
      trigger: none | trigger | [ string ] # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if skipped (only works for Azure Repos).
      name: string # repository name (format depends on 'type'; does not accept variables).
      ref: string # ref name to checkout; defaults to 'refs/heads/main'. The branch checked out by default whenever the resource trigger fires.
      type: string # Type of repository: git, github, githubenterprise, and bitbucket.

Example from Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline:
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo 
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection # ID of the service endpoint connecting
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyBitbucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitbucketServiceConnection # ID of the service endpoint connecting
    name: MyBitbucketOrgOrUser/MyBitbucketRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository 
    endpoint: MyAzureReposGitServiceConnection # ID of the service endpoint connecting
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
- checkout: MyBitbucketRepo
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

Note: You can find information on how to add the service connections for your repositories in Common service connection types.

If the repositories resource you are using is from another Azure DevOps organization or another platform (such as GitHub, Bitbucket), you first need to set up a corresponding service connection (endpoint) to connection to the outside organization/platform. And then use this endpoint to the endpoint key when defining the repositories resource in the YAML pipeline.
See "Repository resource definition".

EDIT:
When you define the repositories resource, you set its alias as 'my-devops'. But when you reference the template from it on the line "- template: applications/deploy.yaml@mydevops", the alias is "mydevops" that is not consistent with the previous one. On the checkout task "- checkout: mydevops", you also used the wrong alias.
This should be the reason of this error you got.


yes correct i have the correct service connection,. the problem seems to be around the 2 checkout: lines because if i remove the checkout: self it works.. Basically, in the template file - template: applications/deploy.yaml@mydevops  which is in the mydevops repo in github. i am checkout out self and also itself with name mydevops. when i use self it checkouts the source repo. somehow it doesn't like that.

@sbolla, you used the wrong alias of the repositories resource. For more details, see EDIT in my above answer.

hello @Bright Ran. THank you. But thats not what it was. I was replacing some strings hence missed that. overall issue is present and it resolves when you specify like this. you can repriduce this issue easily also

checkout: self
checkout: ${{ parameters.REPO_NAME }}


The following resolved it
assume you have 2 repos, mycldops/my-devops and mycldops/myrepo12
you have 1 yaml file with file name some_deploy.yaml in mycldops/myrepo12 as shown below and in this its calling a template called deploy.yaml which is in another repo mycldops/my-devops. When you want to checkout both repos in template then you can pass it as a parameter.
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: TARGET_ENV
    displayName: Target Environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my-devops
      type: github
      endpoint: myrepo12-svc-conn
      name: mycldops/my-devops
      ref: roundrobinbr
    - repository: myrepo12
      type: github
      endpoint: myrepo12-svc-conn
      name: mycldops/myrepo12
      ref: main

variables:
  - group: common
  - name: REPO_NAME
    value: myrepo12

stages:
  - template: deploy.yaml@my-devops
    parameters:
      TARGET_ENV: ${{ parameters.TARGET_ENV }}
      REPO_NAME: ${{ variables.REPO_NAME }}


Repo: mycldops/my-devops
stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage

    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        environment: $(ADO_ENVIRONMENT_NAME)
        displayName: Deploy
        pool:
          name: self-hosted
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - checkout: ${{ parameters.REPO_NAME }}

                - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

                - task: Bash@3
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      # Write your commands here
                      
                      echo 'Hello world'

